# Check if words are spelled correctly in list

Tags: python, loops, split, list-comprehension, any

I've been given a dictionary with the following words:

```
dictionary = ['all', 'an', 'and', 'as', 'closely', 'correct', 'equivocal',
              'examine', 'indication', 'is', 'means', 'minutely', 'or', 'scrutinize',
              'sign', 'the', 'to', 'uncertain']
```

I'm trying to write a spellchecker that tells which words in an input sentence are spelled incorrectly.

The expected output is either:

A) print incorrectly spelled words each at a new line

or

B) **only if all words** are spelled correctly, print OK

Here's the code I've come up with so far:

```
dictionary = ['all', 'an', 'and', 'as', 'closely', 'correct', 'equivocal',
              'examine', 'indication', 'is', 'means', 'minutely', 'or',
              'scrutinize', 'sign', 'the', 'to', 'uncertain']  

text = input().split()
counter = 0

for x in text:
    if x not in dictionary:
        counter += 1
        print(x, end='\n')
    elif not counter:
        print("OK")
```

Two sample inputs and outputs were given as examples to the expected results:

Sample Input 1:

```
srutinize is to examene closely and minutely
```

Sample Output 1:

```
srutinize

examene
```

Sample Input 2:

```
all correct
```

Sample Output 2:

```
OK
```

Code works fine for input 1, but input 2 instead of printing OK is printing `all correct` instead of `OK`.

Comment: Just updated the post. Really need some guidance here, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there with your updated code. You should just check the counter once after the loop has finished, instead of doing it for every word:

```
for x in text:
    if x not in dictionary:
        counter += 1
        print(x, end='\n')

if counter == 0:
    print("OK")
```

There is also a fancier way of solving the problem using a list comprehension:

```
text = input().split()

typos = [word for word in text if word not in dictionary]
if typos:
    print("\n".join(typos))
else:
    print("OK")
```

Comment: Thank you Selcuk, that was super helpful.